# tun/machen plus infinitive? (without direct objects)

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification, infinitive

There are a few verbs that accept infinitives, such as "*müssen*", "*wollen*". Some other verbs need a direct object before the infinitive, such as "*lassen*" (e.g. "Ich lasse meine Haare schneiden.").

But the sentences below baffled me in understanding its structure and meaning:

- Wo ich im Haushalt helfe, ach Gott **kochen tu** immer ich.
- Wäsche **waschen mach** ich nicht so gerne.

I believe they should have used "tue" and "mache" but in spoken language, they tend to drop the final "e". But my main concern is the structure "tun/machen + infinitive".

Is it similar to the structure in english "I **do eat** vegetables."? Is it also implied that the speaker wants to emphasize things? If not, then what does it mean?

According to [Verlaufsform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlaufsform), "*tun + infinitive*" is used in Bavaria, and is unfortunately not considered correct in Standard German. I found no information regarding "*machen + infinitive*"; is this even grammatically correct?

Comment: Actually, it is *Wäschewaschen*, i.e., a composite noun: *„(Das) Wäschewaschen mach(e) ich nicht so gerne.“* And in the first sentence, there is a comma missing: *ach Gott, kochen ...* versus *ach, Gott kochen ...*

Comment: Yes, it's regional or archaic but the examples you've gave us have nothing to do with the progressive/contineous tense. So, the judgment at "Verlaufsform" is irrelevant for them.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the two sentences is completely different.

*Tun* + infinitive is a heavily stigmatised combination that however, in the given sentence, fulfils a simple and in my view completely legitimate purpose: By adding the meaningless auxiliary *tun*, the main verb can be [topicalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization), i.e. put in first position.

An example from a prestigious newspaper:

> Die Fed versuchte sich mit einer kleinen Senkung aus der Affäre zu ziehen und diese als eine Anpassung mitten in einem (Zinserhöhungs-)Zyklus zu verkaufen. **Glauben tut** das nicht jeder: […] [faz.net](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/finanzen/finanzmarkt/zinssenkung-in-usa-kein-befreiungsschlag-fuer-die-fed-16313023.html)

The meaning is not different from the variant without *tun* (with the exception of the effect of the topicalisation of the main verb). There is no emphasis of the act, as in English *do believe*, nor is there an aspectual distinction involved. (This might be different in dialects; it is unfortunate that the Wikipedia article [Verlaufsform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlaufsform) does not have any references in that regard.)

Moving on to the second case, *machen* cannot generally combine with an infinitive.* What might look like a combination of *machen* with an infinitive is actually an infinitive being used as an object (noun-like). Note the following contrast:

> *Waschen mach ich Wäsche nicht so gern.
> *Wäsche mach ich nicht so gern waschen.

vs.

> Waschen tu ich Wäsche nicht so gern.
> Wäsche tu ich nicht so gern waschen.

The contrast arises because *tun* + infinitive (like any combination of a verb with the infinitive of another verb) allows the object of *waschen* to be split form its governing verb. The infinitive used as an object (noun-like) with *machen*, however, cannot be split from its own object *Wäsche*.

When I say *noun-like*, I do not mean the same as conversions of the type *lesen* > *beim Lesen*, where *lesen* changes part of speech. Rather, in instances such as the one you gave, a whole verb phrase is *in toto* taken as a noun. Another example, with a whole verb phrase taken as a noun and functioning as a subject:

> **Immer nur arbeiten** macht auch keinen Spaß.

Or, with the verb phrase containing an object:

> **Bestellkarte einlegen** macht auch wieder Extraarbeit. (Fallada)

*<sub>The exception are old-fashioned causatives of the form *der Kasus macht mich lachen* (Goethe).</sub>

Comment: I couldn't describe it better.